# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "edit" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Course"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, express-handlebars

I am developing an app but when I try to open or edit a course I am getting the error.
It might be something because of mongoose, but since I develop my first Node pet project, I cannot find a solution for this problem

```
router.get('/:id/edit', async (request, response) => {
  if (!request.query.allow) {
    return response.redirect('/')
  }

  const course = await Course.findById(request.params.id)

  response.render('course-edit', {
    title: `Edit ${course.title}`,
    course,
  })
})

router.post('/edit', async (request, response) => {
  const { id } = request.body
  delete request.body.id

  await Course.findByIdAndUpdate(id, request.body)

  response.redirect('/courses')
})

router.get('/:id', async (request, response) => {
  const course = await Course.findById(request.params.id)

  response.render('course', {
    layout: 'empty',
    title: `Course ${course.title}`,
    course,
  })
})





const course = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    img: String,
})
```

Comment: Can you add Course schema code? Also do you send a valid object id in the url?

Comment: @SuleymanSah Added schema code to my question

Maybe I send invalid id but I don't know how to check :(

Comment: Which url do you use to access this route?

Comment: @SuleymanSah /courses/{{ id }}

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is expecting an `ObjectId`, but it is getting a string, try to use this:

```
const convert = Types.ObjectId(<your id or id variable goes here>)
```

And then use the convert variable normally in your code

Note that you can rename convert to whatever you want :), hope this answers your question!